# .NET Core interop calling convention on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, interop

When using Interop on Linux my app crashed. I managed to narrow it down to the case where the native method returns an union.  When I looked at the core dump with gdb it seemed to me that the calling convention is wrong. I was expecting to see the pointer to the string in register RDI but it contained garbage.

I do not know if it is correct behavior or a bug?

### Environnent

- Fedora 26 linux 4.14.14-200.fc26.x86_64
- dotnet 2.1.4
- gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915

### C++ shared object code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern "C"
union Union {
    int64_t f2;
};

extern "C"
Union crash(const char* msg) {
    std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " start" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " ptr " << (void*)msg << std::endl;
    std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " arg " << msg << std::endl;
    return Union{};
}
```

Compiled using : `g++ -Wall -fPIC -std=c++11 -shared -O0 -g -o libcrash.so crash.cpp`

### C# console app code

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace question
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Union {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        Int64 field2;
    }

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("libcrash.so")]
        static extern Union crash(string s);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            crash("boom !!");
            Console.WriteLine("All Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to specify [`CallingConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention)?

Comment: yes but the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that for the time being .net core does not support [LayoutKind.Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netframework-4.7) in linux. See the [corefx issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27046)